# How can I add buttons to a table's column, that navigate to specific routes upon onClick()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm building a dashboard of sorts as part of a project to learn React and NextJS. I'm stuck on an issue that I have found no solution to online. Any help is appreciated!

So I have a page called 'departments.js', which shows a table like the one in the image below.
[image: 1]

I get the data to fill in the rows and columns from 2 hardcoded JSON stringa:

```
const data = [
        { name: "Customer Service", num: '56', dept:'custserv' },
        { name: "Human Resources", num: '21', dept:'hr' },
        { name: "Quality Assurance", num: '13', dept:'qa' },
        { name: "Marketing", num: '30', dept:'mark' },
        { name: "Research and Development", num: '17', dept:'rnd' },
        { name: "Operations", num: '49', dept:'ops' },
        { name: "Sales", num: '37', dept:'sales' },
        { name: "Distribution", num: '26', dept:'dist' },
        { name: "IT", num: '12', dept:'it' },
      ]

const column = [
        { heading: 'Department', value: 'name' },
        { heading: 'No. of Employees', value: 'num' },
        { heading: 'Actions', value: 'dept' },
    ];
```

The `dept` field in the JSON string should store the name of the js file for that department.

What I want to achieve is - when the user clicks the **View Department** button in the marketing row, the app navigates to `/mark.js`.

I have a separate component for the table:
**Table.js**

```
const Table = ({ data, column }) => {
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {column.map((item, index) => <TableHeadItem item={item} />)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item, index) => <TableRow item={item} column={column} />)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
}

const TableHeadItem = ({ item }) => <th>{item.heading}</th>
const TableRow = ({ item, column }) => (
    <tr>
    {column.map((columnItem, index) => {

      if(columnItem.value.includes('.')) {
        const itemSplit = columnItem.value.split('.')
        return <td>{item[itemSplit[0]][itemSplit[1]]}</td>
      }

      return <td>{item[`${columnItem.value}`]}</td>
    })}
  </tr>
)

export default Table
```

Here is how I build the table in the `departments.js` file:

```
return(
   <div className={styles.tableCont}>
      <Table data={data} column={column} />  {/* data and column JSONs*/}
   </div>
)
```

I tried declaring a function to build the button for each row with the `dept` from the data JSON, but I'm not able to do it. Please advise on how to go about this.

**My failed attempt**

```
const viewDeptBtn = (dept) => {
        return (
            <button className={styles.viewDeptBtn} onClick={() => router.push('/'+dept)}>
                View Department
            </button>
        )
    }

const column = [
        { heading: 'Department', value: 'name' },
        { heading: 'No. of Employees', value: 'num' },
        { heading: 'Actions', value: viewDeptBtn('dept') },
    ];
```

Comment: Have you tried using next/link instead of the button in viewDeptBtn component?

Comment: As per the JSON data you know the paths that you'll need to generate, use getStaticPaths & getStaticProps, then the <Link> component to navigate, your button should be like: <button><Link><a>[]</a></Link></button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is shaped like this:

```json
const data = [
        { name: "Customer Service", num: '56', dept:'custserv' },
        { name: "Human Resources", num: '21', dept:'hr' },
        { name: "Quality Assurance", num: '13', dept:'qa' },
        { name: "Marketing", num: '30', dept:'mark' },
        { name: "Research and Development", num: '17', dept:'rnd' },
        { name: "Operations", num: '49', dept:'ops' },
        { name: "Sales", num: '37', dept:'sales' },
        { name: "Distribution", num: '26', dept:'dist' },
        { name: "IT", num: '12', dept:'it' },
      ]
```

Then to produce the table rows you'd just have to do the following:

```
const Button = ({ dept }) => (
    <button onClick={() => router.push(`/${dept}`)}>View Department</button>
);

const TableRow = ({ item }) => (
    <tr>
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td>{item.num}</td>
        <td>
            <Button dept={item.dept} />
        </td>
    </tr>
);

const TableHeadItem = ({ item }) => <th>{item.heading}</th>;

export default function Table({data, column}) {
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {column.map((item, index) => (
                        <TableHeadItem item={item} key={index} />
                    ))}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {data.map((item) => (
                    <TableRow item={item} key={item.num} />
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```